# SSRS datasource works locally but not on server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have this datasource for SSRS:

```
Data Source=www.myWebsite.com;Initial Catalog=myDB
```

It works on my local machine, but when I deploy it to the production server it doesn't work.

The error message I got is

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection)

The strange thing is that when I changed it to

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDB
```

it works on the server.

It looks like the server recognizes `localhost` but not `www.myWebsite.com` (it is the server's own web address).

I also have another report deployed to that server which connects to database on a different server:

```
Data Source=www.OtherWebsite.com;Initial Catalog=otherDB
```

and it is working. So the server would recognizes everything except it's own web address.

Has anyone seen that before?

Comment: seems to be a routing issue, why aren't you using the server's FQDN on your internal network for the Data Source if I may ask? (ex. mydatabaseserver.mynetwork.com)

Comment: @RandomUs1r because my local machine is not on the same domain / network of the server, so FQDN won't work on my local machine. I want the datasource to work on both so the report will be exactly the same on local and server.

Comment: in that case what happens when you use the IP instead?  Edit: you'll probably have to pass a username and password.

Comment: @criticalfix I think that's the case when you are using a shared data source. I am not using shared. When I changed it to localhost and deployed, it worked; so that means it is using the datasource with the report.

Comment: Okay, but shared .rds datasources would allow you to keep the .rdl files the same while running against different data sources locally and on the server.  If they're on different networks you may have to do it that way.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I checked that the username and password are saved in the credentials. I tried with IP address and still no luck (same result as using www.myWebsite.com on both local and server)

Comment: Figured out, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, silly me...
We have a firewall on the server that blocks all incoming connections except a few (my local machine is on that exception list).
When I use the www.myWebsite.com address it thinks it is coming from outside so it blocks it.

I think I will have to use different rds if I want to keep the rdl the same.

Comment: firewalls are always a gotcha in regards to SQL services :)